# Issue CRA and Github actions

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, create-react-app, firebase-tools

I recently tried to deploy my app with Firebase-tools (v11.23.1) and the initial deployment worked but doesn't work on the next try. I'm new to firebase and Github actions. Anybody got a clue how to fix this, help would be very welcome.

yaml snippet

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
"on":
    push:
        branches:
            - main
jobs:
    build_and_deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - run: npm ci && npm run build
            - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
              with:
                  repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
                  firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_XX}}"
                  channelId: live
                  projectId: XX
```

The action log CI on && Build (Error: Process completed with exit code 1.):

```
Run npm ci && npm run build
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1542 packages, and audited 1543 packages in 21s

231 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

> concept-of-site@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.


Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: "**How to update Node.js 12 to 16?**": Use `actions/checkout@v3`. For that build and deploy error, include your workflow in your question along with the failure logs.

Comment: @Azeem Just tried again with actions/checkout@v3 but to no avail.

Comment: Please do not add [images of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) edit your post and add your yaml snippet and your logs

Comment: @Fcmam5 Have corrected my post, thank you.

Comment: Your title mentions "How to update Node.js 12 to 16?" while it's not mentioned anywhere in the question, you may want to update the title to reflect that you are having a problem with create-react-app build and github actions

Answer (score 2):

Your pipeline is not failing because of Firebase, it fails because of `npm run build`, apparently that doesn't work when `CI` environment variable is set to `true` as it checks for linter rules

> "*When creating a build of your application with `npm run build` linter
> warnings are not checked by default. Like `npm test`, you can force
> the build to perform a linter warning check by setting the environment
> variable `CI`. If any warnings are encountered then the build fails." - source: [CRA CI](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#continuous-integration)*

You can disable that behavior for now by adding [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv) with `CI=false`

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
    build_and_deploy:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        - run: npm ci
        - run: npm run build
          env:
            CI: false
        - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
          with:
            repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
            firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_XX}}"
            channelId: live
            projectId: XX
```

One other option is to add `CI=false` to your `package.json`'s `build` command so it would be:

```
"build": "CI=false react-scripts build"
```

Or maybe better, consider fixing your linting warnings/errors :)

Comment: Thank you for the fix and source  source: CRA CI I was not looking there. Fixed my linting ;)